# VBA excel if cell contains character then split text to columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have a fairly simple piece of code that doesn't seem to work. I need the cells to split if a word contains the character "," but only if it does. I thought that Using IF, Then, Else would work but every time it reaches a cell with no "," then i end up with "TextToColumns method of Range class failed"

```
If InStr(1, (Range("C32").Value), ",") > 0 Then

Range("C32").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B14"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
Other:=True, OtherChar:=","

Else

End If
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: For me if there's no `,` in the cell, `ELSE` condition is executed and hence doesn't give error. May be posting your sample data could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks guys, i'm not quite sure where the problem is either, it works about 80% of the time. This is attached to the bottom of a very long string of API calls, i'll search through and see if i can find the problem and will post back with what i find or else will post the code asking for help. Maybe separating this code out and using call would stop the error.

Comment: You are not referencing the workbook nor the worksheet in your code. If somewhere else the ActiveSheet change, you may experience those kind of trouble. Maybe try to specify the worksheet you intend to work on in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok. I've try it, and it works.

```
Sub Split()
If InStr(1, (Range("C2").Value), ",") > 0 Then
Range("C2").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B3"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
Other:=True, OtherChar:=","
Else
MsgBox "kk"
End If
End Sub
```

With cel without "," I get msgbox "kk" - everytime. I'm using MS 2010, maybe thats where the problem is?

Answer (score -1):

You do not need a program for it. Just use Text to Columns from Data ribbon with `,` as data separator. If the line does not contain a comma, then the line will not be split.